# LeetCode 1115: Print FooBar Alternately

Tags: c++, beginner, algorithm, programming-challenge, comparative-review

I'm posting two solutions for LeetCode's "Print FooBar Alternately". If you'd like to review, please do. Thank you!

#### [Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/print-foobar-alternately/)

Suppose you are given the following code:

```
class FooBar {
  public void foo() {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      print("foo");
    }
  }

  public void bar() {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      print("bar");
    }
  }
}
```

The same instance of FooBar will be passed to two different threads. Thread A will call foo() while thread B will call bar(). Modify the given program to output "foobar" n times.

#### Example 1:

```
Input: n = 1
Output: "foobar"
Explanation: There are two threads being fired asynchronously. One of them calls foo(), while the other calls bar(). "foobar" is being output 1 time.
```

#### Example 2:

```
Input: n = 2
Output: "foobarfoobar"
Explanation: "foobar" is being output 2 times.
```

#### Code 1 using `.notify_all()`

```
// The following block might slightly improve the execution time;
// Can be removed;
static const auto __optimize__ = []() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    std::cout.tie(nullptr);
    return 0;
}();

// Most of headers are already included;
// Can be removed;
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <functional>

struct FooBar {
        FooBar(const int num) : num(num) {}

        void foo(const std::function<void()> printFoo) {
            for (std::size_t iter = 0; iter < num; ++iter) {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locked(coordinator);
                stream_status.wait(locked, [&]() {
                    return !bar_is_on_flag;
                });

                printFoo();

                bar_is_on_flag = true;

                stream_status.notify_all();
            }

            return;
        }

        void bar(const std::function<void()> printBar) {
            for (std::size_t iter = 0; iter < num; ++iter) {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locked(coordinator);
                stream_status.wait(locked, [&]() {
                    return bar_is_on_flag;
                });

                printBar();

                bar_is_on_flag = false;

                stream_status.notify_all();
            }

            return;
        }


    private:
        int num;
        std::mutex coordinator;
        std::condition_variable stream_status;
        bool bar_is_on_flag = false;
};
```

#### Code 2 using `.notify_one()`

```
// The following block might slightly improve the execution time;
// Can be removed;
static const auto __optimize__ = []() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    std::cout.tie(nullptr);
    return 0;
}();

// Most of headers are already included;
// Can be removed;
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <functional>

struct FooBar {
        FooBar(const int num) : num(num) {}

        void foo(const std::function<void()> printFoo) {
            for (std::size_t iter = 0; iter < num; ++iter) {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locked(coordinator);
                stream_status.wait(locked, [&]() {
                    return !bar_is_on_flag;
                });

                printFoo();

                bar_is_on_flag = true;

                stream_status.notify_one();
            }

            return;
        }

        void bar(const std::function<void()> printBar) {
            for (std::size_t iter = 0; iter < num; ++iter) {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locked(coordinator);
                stream_status.wait(locked, [&]() {
                    return bar_is_on_flag;
                });

                printBar();

                bar_is_on_flag = false;

                stream_status.notify_one();
            }

            return;
        }


    private:
        int num;
        std::mutex coordinator;
        std::condition_variable stream_status;
        bool bar_is_on_flag = false;
};
```

Comment: Unless I am missing something obvious, there is no difference between Code 1 and Code 2.

Comment: Oh. It is almost impossible to notice. Now I see. I don't think there is any difference in this context, neither functionally not performance wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations on the correct use of the C++11 condition variables! As mentioned by vnp, there will be no difference functionally or performance wise in this specific case, as there is only ever one thread waiting while the other notifies. Some possible improvements though:

## Unnecessary `return` statements

You don't need a `return` statement at the end of a `void` function.

## Consider notifying without holding the lock

If you hold the lock while calling `notify_one()` or `notify_all()` on a condition variable, it is possible that the other thread will be woken up, which immediately tries to lock the mutex, but if the notifying thread still holds it it will fail. This might then cause the thread to immediately do call the kernel to wait for the mutex to be unlocked. So it is better to surround the part that really needs locking with curly braces, and put the notify call outside it:

```
for (...)
{
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locked(coordinator);
        stream_status.wait(locked, ...);
        print(...);
        bar_is_on_flag = ...;
    }

    stream_status.notify_one();
}
```